# Hadoop Custom Input format with the new API

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm a newbie to Hadoop and I'm stuck with the following problem. What I'm trying to do is to map a shard of the database (please don't ask why I need to do that etc) to a mapper, then do certain operation on this data, output the results to reducers and use that output again to do the second phase map/reduce job on the same data using the same shard format.
Hadoop does not provide any input method to send a shard of the database. You can only send line by line using `LineInputFormat` and `LineRecordReader`. `NLineInputFormat` doesn't also help in this case. I need to extend `FileInputFormat` and `RecordReader` classes to write my own `InputFormat`. I have been advised to use `LineRecordReader` since the underlying code already deals with the `FileSplits` and all the problems associated with splitting the files.
All I need to do now is to override the `nextKeyValue()` method which I don't exactly know how.

```
       for(int i=0;i<shard_size;i++){
               if(lineRecordReader.nextKeyValue()){
lineValue.append(lineRecordReader.getCurrentValue().getBytes(),0,lineRecordReader.getCurrentValue().getLength());
  }
}
```

The above code snippet is the one that wrote but somehow doesn't work well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to put into your input files connection strings and some other indications where to find the shard. 
 
Mapper will take this information, connect to the database and do a job. I would not suggest t o convert result sets to hadoop's writable classes - it will hinder performance.
The problem I see to be addressed - is to have enough splits of this relatively small input.
You can simply create enough small files with a few shards references each, or you can tweak input format to build small splits. Second way will be more flexible.

Comment: What I did, is something like this

Answer (score 0):

What I did, is something like this. I wrote my own record reader to read n lines at a time and send them to mappers as input

```
public boolean nextKeyValue() throws IOException,
```

InterruptedException {

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        if (!lineRecordReader.nextKeyValue()) {
            return false;
        }
        lineKey = lineRecordReader.getCurrentKey();
        lineValue = lineRecordReader.getCurrentValue();
        sb.append(lineValue.toString());
        sb.append(eol);
    }
    lineValue.set(sb.toString());
    //System.out.println(lineValue.toString());

    return true;

    // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
}
```

how do you thin

Comment: Not everything is clear here, but It looks like you have to split in the small parts in the inputFormat, when you decide on splits. After whole big block of data is fed to the RecordReader - you have no choice but to give it to your mapper.

Comment: @DavidGruzman, what it does is, it reader 5 lines (5 can be changed to any number) and sends it to a mapper. The mapper takes these 5 lines of input, does certain operations on it, produces several outputs with different keys and values then sends them to reducers. How input is split is encapsulated by the linRecordReader object.

Comment: Let me put it this way to be more clear. In a classic WordCount application, what they do, is read each line into a mapper from the file. The mapper just outputs, (word, one), the reducers then aggregate these values, right? Wouldn't it be better to send each mapper a file (not just one line), then read line by line inside the mapper, subsequently output (word, one). Then use a combiner to aggregate intermediate values (since there will be many repeating words) and send the results to the reducers. That would be faster because it doesn't require too many mapper instances and we can utilize cmb

Comment: @DavidGruzman, of course the above would be true if you have limited number of clusters not thousands of them. If you have gazillion number of nodes to utilize, you might wanna spread your data as much as possible. But, in my case, I would be using maximum 10 or so nodes as hadoop cluster